# How does the JavaScript singleton pattern with cached static property work?

Tags: javascript, singleton

This is my modified example based on [one by Rob Dodson](http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/).

```
function User() {  
    // do we have an existing instance?
    if (User.instance) {
        return User.instance;
    }

    // proceed as normal
    this.firstName = 'John';
    this.lastName = 'Doe';

    // cache
    User.instance = this;

    // implicit return
    // return this;
}

a = new User();
b = new User();
b.firstName = "Paul"
console.log(a)
```

I'm just learning, so I may use lay terminology, but if I understand correctly, `User.instance = this;` clones `User`, and that clone becomes the only `User` we have access to anymore. So the full process it goes through is like this:

`a = new User();`

do we have an existing `User.instance`? No. So continue through the code and set `a.firstName` to John, and `a.lastName` to Doe. And now make a copy of `this` object with the name John Doe and set it as a permanent part of the `User` constructor. What makes it permanent? Because the code will never reach the line setting it again. Why? Because…

`b = new User();`

do we have an existing `User.instance`? Yes. So `return` the `User.instance` we already have stored, and move back out of the function.

**How is `a` is referring to `User.instance`?** --I don’t see how the implicit return of `this` is what returns to `a`--whereas with `b` it's the clone.

Comment: Functions can also have properties, so setting `User.instance = this;` saves the first created insatnce on the function itsself. So when it's called again, it detects its instance property exists and just returns the cached instance. And b is not a clone, it's a reference to the same object a references to, hence when you change b.firstName to paul, a.firstName is also paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I understand correctly, `User.instance = this;` clones User, and that clone becomes …
>   … make a copy of this object …

No. Assignment does not copy/clone objects, it does assign the very same object reference from the right hand side to the variable (or property etc) on the left hand side. That's why `a === User.instance` and `b = User.instance`.

The same happens in `b = new User();` - the return value of `new User()` is not cloned or something, but assigned directly to `b`.

Comment: What about `a = new User();` ? why wouldn't the return value be undefined the first time it runs?

Comment: Because constructors that are invoked with `new` implicitly return the instance - as the comment in your code mentions